# ImageView tags going missing

Tags: android, imageview, android-relativelayout

I'm making a basic card game for up to four players and I have a problem I can't work out.

I have several layouts stacked on top of one another (match_parent).

I have added imageviews to each layout and added tags to them before passing the cardView to the next method.

```
 void animateCard(int finalX, int finalY, final ImageView cardView, final String playerId, final int n){

    int duration = 180;

    ObjectAnimator animX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(cardView, "x", finalX);
    ObjectAnimator animY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(cardView, "y", finalY);

   animX.setDuration(duration);
   animY.setDuration(duration);

   // animX.start();

    AnimatorSet animSetXY = new AnimatorSet();
    animSetXY.playTogether(animX, animY);
    animSetXY.start();

    animSetXY.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {


            float cardX = cardView.getX();
            float cardY = cardView.getY();



                if (playerId.equals("human")) {


                }

                else if (playerId.equals("topPlayer")){


                    Log.e("TopPlayerHAnd: ", String.valueOf(topPlayerHand));

                    Log.e("cardViewGetTag: ", String.valueOf(cardView.getTag()));

                    Log.e("parent: ", String.valueOf(cardView.getParent()));

                    Log.e("TPAL tag at 0: ", String.valueOf(topPlayerAreaLayout.getChildAt(0).getTag()));


                }





        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });


}
```

The issue is that attempting to get the tag by calling                         Log.e("TPAL tag at 0: ", String.valueOf(topPlayerAreaLayout.getChildAt(0).getTag())); is returning "null".

However,                         Log.e("cardViewGetTag: ", String.valueOf(cardView.getTag()));

returns the actual tag and

Log.e("parent: ", String.valueOf(cardView.getParent()));

logs android.widget.RelativeLayout{7133a69 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-1184,720 #7f0c0061 app:id/topPlayerAreaLayout} as the layout in which the cardView is found.

topPlayerAreaLayout.getChildCount(); returns the correct number of children, but no tags!

I've been beating my head against the wall for days with this, but no result.

edit: This is the method where I set tags for the views:
edit2: tags survive intact through to animateCard method if playerId.equals("human")

```
 void addCardsToTopAndBottomHands(final String whichPlayer, final RelativeLayout thisLayout, final int initialCardX, final int initialCardY, ArrayList playerDeck, int totalCardsToAdd){

        Log.e("addCardsLayout: ", String.valueOf(thisLayout));

    int n = 0;

    String cardTag = "";

    while( n< totalCardsToAdd){

        final int q = n;

        int duration = 180 *(n+1);

        int multiplier = 0;

        final ImageView thisCardView = new ImageView(this);

        playerDeck.add(thisDeck.get(0));
        String cardTag = String.valueOf(thisDeck.get(0));



        thisDeck.remove(0);
        thisCardView.setTag(cardTag);


        if (whichPlayer.equals("human")) {

            multiplier =((playingCardWidth*(q+1))+9);


            final int cardId = getResources().getIdentifier(String.valueOf(playerDeck.get(n)), "drawable", getPackageName());


            thisCardView.setImageResource(cardId);


        }

        else {
            thisCardView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cardback);

            multiplier = halfCardWidth *(q+1);

            Log.e("playerName: ", whichPlayer);
            Log.e("playerDeck: ", String.valueOf(playerDeck));

        }

        final int cardXCoord = initialCardX + multiplier;
        final int cardYCoord = initialCardY + multiplier;





        CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(duration, duration) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {



                thisLayout.addView(thisCardView);

                Log.e("playerName: ", whichPlayer);
                Log.e("counting in: ", String.valueOf(thisLayout.getChildCount()));
                Log.e ("thisCardTag: ", String.valueOf(thisCardView.getTag()));
                Log.e("thisLayout: ", String.valueOf(thisLayout));

                Log.e("TPAL count: ", String.valueOf(topPlayerAreaLayout.getChildCount()));
                String message = "Tag at " + String.valueOf(q);

                Log.e(message, String.valueOf(topPlayerAreaLayout.getChildAt(q).getTag()));


                //TODO: TPAL imageView tags are intact here! WTF did they go?


                thisCardView.requestLayout();
                thisCardView.setX(centreCardX);
                thisCardView.setY(centreCardY);
                thisCardView.getLayoutParams().height = playingCardHeight;
                thisCardView.getLayoutParams().width = playingCardWidth;

               // Log.e("this q: ", String.valueOf(q) );

              if (whichPlayer.equals("human")|| whichPlayer.equals("topPlayer")) {

                    animateCard(cardXCoord, initialCardY, thisCardView, whichPlayer, q);

                }

                else if (whichPlayer.equals("leftPlayer")|| whichPlayer.equals("rightPlayer")){

                          animateCard(initialCardX, cardYCoord, thisCardView, whichPlayer, q );

              }

            }
        }; countDownTimer.start();

        n++;

    }

}
```

Comment: also post code where you setTag() for your View .

Comment: Thanks Adnan. I've done that.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand your code. Why do you try to get the tag from `String.valueOf(topPlayerAreaLayout.getChildAt(0).getTag())` when you have a `cardView` as parameter of your `animateCard` method? Or is it a different cardView? And where do you get it from?

Comment: And btw, I'd suggest to use a `for` instead of a `while` in `addCardsToTopAndBottomHands` as you have a defined number of elements.

Comment: Hi Elsafar, I'm getting it from String.valueOf(topPlayerAreaLayout.getChildAt(0).getTag()) because this is the first place that I can identify that it's not showing up in the layout. I actually don't need it until later on (when I don't have a cardView. Yes, I should use a for loop.